# Return in parameter variable while call web service

Tags: java, c#, web-services

I have simple web service on Java:

```
package tst;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class TstService {
    @WebMethod
    public int tst(String data, String response)
    {
        response ="Ok";
        return 1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args ){

        Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:1234/TstService", new TstService());
    }
}
```

Trying to call it from C#:

```
namespace websrvClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceReference1.TstServiceClient srv = new ServiceReference1.TstServiceClient();
            String arg0 = "aaa";
            String arg1 = null;

            int i = srv.tst(arg0,arg1);

            Console.WriteLine("tst returns {0} {1} {2}",i,arg0,arg1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

C# client calls fine and gets function return - `1`, but it not retrieves `response` 
string variable. How to solve this problem?

Web service WSDL:

```
<!--
 Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e. 
-->
<!--
 Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e. 
-->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://tst/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tst/" name="TstServiceService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://tst/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:1234/TstService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="tst">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:tst"/>
</message>
<message name="tstResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:tstResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="TstService">
<operation name="tst">
<input wsam:Action="http://tst/TstService/tstRequest" message="tns:tst"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://tst/TstService/tstResponse" message="tns:tstResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="TstServicePortBinding" type="tns:TstService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="tst">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="TstServiceService">
<port name="TstServicePort" binding="tns:TstServicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:1234/TstService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: You're simply not returning the response variable which is why your c# app is unable to retrieve it. In your case your web service is expected to return an `int` and it does so by returning `1`.

Comment: Yes, I got  `1` in function return. But how to get `response ="Ok"` to C# application?

Comment: even if you call method  tst in java , parameter String response will be changed only inside method body. http://jonskeet.uk/java/passing.html. To solve it you need to wrap tst  parameters in object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your web service method to return complex structure. 
So declare return structure first:

```
public class ReturnDto 
{
    public int ReturnValue;   
    public string ResponseText;
}
```

..and change your web method to following:

```
public ReturnDto tst(String data, String response)
{
        ReturnDto ret = new ReturnDto();
        ret.ReturnValue = 1;
        ret.ResponseText = "Ok";
        return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebMethod` `tst` is defined to return `int` (`public int tst`) and you return 1 (`return 1;`), that's why the value of `response` is not returned.

If you need both to be returned you should create a serializable object that contains both, for example a class, and that should be your return type.